# Кодировка писем для mail.ru

Tags: email, php, кодировка

Добрый день! Есть функция, которая отправляет письмо с аттачментом. Все хорошо работает, проверял на gmail и yandex, но вот на ящики mail.ru приходит черт знает что, какие-то проблемы с кодировкой видимо. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема. 
Вот код:

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message, $send_html) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $send_html."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
       $data['error'] = 0;
    } else {
        $data['error'] = 1;
    }
```

Comment: может 8BIT попробовать в Content-Transfer-Encoding?

Comment: Не помогло. Вместо текста письма, который отлично приходит на gmail и yandex, на mail.ru приходит: 
'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

пёп╡п╟п╤п╟п╣п╪я▀п╧, п©п╬п╩я┐я┤п╟я┌п╣п╩я▄!

п▓п╟п╪п╦ п╠я▀п╩ п╬я┌п©я─п╟п╡п╩п╣п╫ п╥п╟п©я─п╬я│ п╫п╟ п©я─п╟п╧я│-п╩п╦я│я┌ п║п╣я─п╣п╢п╫п╦п╨п╬п╡п╬.

п⌡я▌п╠я▀п╣ п╡п╬п©я─п╬я│я▀ п▓я▀ п╪п╬п╤п╣я┌п╣ п╥п╟п╢п╟я┌я▄ п©п╬ я┌п╣п╩п╣я└п╬п╫я┐

и т.д'

А вместо вложенного файла текст:
'JVBERi0xLjQNJeLjz9MNCjI0IDAgb2JqDTw8L0xpbmVhcml6ZWQgMS9MIDkwODQ4OC9PIDI2L0UgNzU4MzkxL04gMy9UIDkwNzg5My9IIFsgMTE3NiAzNDddPj4NZW5kb2JqDSAgICAgICAgICAgICAg...'